# How can I restrict results in an Access SELECT Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm working in Access, querying an assignment table between two tables having a many-to-many relationship. Values from the external Data table are collected together into a group, and that group is given an identifying value from the external ID table. In the target table, the ID value repeats only for each Data item in the group. The Data values may repeat, but never under the same ID value.

```
IDVal   DataVal
- - - - - -
A       100
A       200
A       300
A       400
- - - - - -
B       200
B       300
B       400
B       500
- - - - - -
C       100
C       200
C       300
C       400
C       500
```

From another process, I have an incoming set of Data values (say, 200, 300, 400, 500). I'm trying to write a single query against this table that returns the ID associated with *only* those incoming values.
If I write a regular SELECT query, then I'll get back both B and C as my ID values.

How I can make my query return only the ID identifying *exactly* the data set I'm looking for? I'm not  yet proficient enough with SQL to manage this with with a single query.

Comment: when you say exactly the data set you're looking for, how do you plan on including this in the query besides hardcoding values?  please post anything you've already written

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that: I can include hard-coded values, because I'm creating VBA code that will generate the query. So I have the incoming values, and I can add them as literals if necessary as the code assembles the query.

Comment: how complex is the data, i.e. do you ever have different `IDVal` interspersed?  are the `DataVal` values always in sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query (possible create by Query constructor)

```
SELECT Data.IdVal, Count(Data.DataVal) AS [Count-DataVal]
   ,Count(Test.Data) AS [Count-Data1]
   ,Sum(IIf(IsNull([test].[data]),1,0)) AS sNN
FROM Test RIGHT JOIN Data ON Test.Data = Data.DataVal
GROUP BY Data.Id
HAVING (((Sum(IIf(IsNull([test].[data]),1,0)))=0));
```

Result

| IdVal | Count-DataVal | Count-Data1 | sNN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | 4 | 4 | 0 |

Without filter by HAVING

| Id | Count-DataVal | Count-Data1 | sNN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4 | 3 | 1 |
| B | 4 | 4 | 0 |
| C | 5 | 4 | 1 |

Test table `Test` - incoming data

| Data |
| --- |
| 200 |
| 300 |
| 400 |
| 500 |

Comment: Interesting. That looks like it can be made to do the job. Thanks.